# IE8 Accelerators are not working

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Im afraid about this, I cannot use any accelerator preview like Translator or Shop & Save, Why?

```
IE version : 8.0.6001.18702IC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to be more specific here.  What exactly is going wrong?  Are you getting errors?  How does it fail?

Off the top of my head, check and see if your accelerators are enabled:  Tools->Manage Addons, then the 'Accelerators' option on the left side.  Anything you want to use should be enabled.  Translater should show there, and may be disabled.